# Getting Error: Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group

Tags: sql, teradata

Hi I am getting below error:   "Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group" even after Assigning GROUP BY

```
    SELECT OA.CustNmr 
,TRIM(COALESCE(A.AcctName,' ') ||' '|| COALESCE(A.Acct2Name,' ') )AS AcctStyling 
,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY  OA.CustNmr, A.LocationNR, AcctStyling)  AS CNT_Cust
    FROM wa.tsn_Open OA
    JOIN Account1 A ON OA.AcctNr = A.AcctNr
    WHERE AcctStatCd = 'O' --Open
    GROUP BY 1
```

Any insight is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378877/selected-non-aggregate-values-must-be-part-of-the-associated-group)

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  It seems pretty clear:  the `select` columns are inconsistent with the `group by` columns.

Comment: Well,  `AcctStyling` and `LocationNR` are not aggregates nor in the `GROUP BY`. The window function is computed after the `GROUP BY`. What are you really trying to do? Please edit the question or delete it and post another.

Comment: Thanks everyone I understood where my mistake in my code and corrected it. Now it is working fine. I added the attributes in SELECT in GROUP BY statement: GROUP BY OA.CustNr,AcctStyling, A.LocationID